# How to fix a hangup in my c# application connecting to an external process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, networking, server, tor

I am writing a manager application in C#, designing a GUI for a network server software, a GUI for a software which acts as a webserver with a text file where a user must input configurations.

In my GUI I'm designing, the user types in their configuration and then clicks the button to start the process. It launches the server software and inputs the users configuration no problem, but the issue is the app then freezes after the web server software is started. I think this is happening because it is getting "hung up" per say waiting for the server software to respond, which is it's own process so does not interact directly with the GUI app. I am wondering, is there a way to detach the GUI app from the network server executable after launching it so this hangout does not happen? Thanks very much.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("I am now making sure Tor is running the newest version. If it is not, I will autmatically update tor to the newest verison. Please one minute. You may see CMD flash at you");
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        string script = string.Format("[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))");
        ps.AddScript(script);
        ps.Invoke();
        PowerShell ps1 = PowerShell.Create();
        string script1 = string.Format("choco install tor");
        ps1.AddScript(script1);
        ps1.Invoke();
        if (File.Exists(@"C:\\torrc.txt"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("It looks like you already have a torrc file written. I will start tor now with these configurations. To change the torrc file, use the following window.");
            PowerShell psprestart = PowerShell.Create();
            string starttor = string.Format("tor.exe -f C:\\torrc.txt");
            psprestart.AddScript(starttor);
            psprestart.Invoke();
        }
    }







    public static string config;
    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        config = richTextBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.EnableContextMenu();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Torrc file created. Now launching your relay. Please see the above window for the progress. If you see 'Testing indicates your ORPort is reachable. Publishing server descriptor, all is good. If you see a failure message, either your tor configuration is incorrect or the connection is being blocked. I will configure Windows Defender Firewall to allow the relay traffic autommatically, but any other firewall will need to be manually configured to allow Tor.");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\torrc.txt", config);
        PowerShell ps2 = PowerShell.Create();
        string scriptfirewallrule = string.Format("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = 'Tor Relay' dir =in action = allow program = 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\tor\\tools\\Tor\\tor.exe' Enable = yes");
        PowerShell psout = PowerShell.Create();
        string scriptfirewallruleout = string.Format("netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = 'Tor Relay' dir =out action = allow program = 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\tor\\tools\\Tor\\tor.exe' Enable = yes");
        psout.AddScript(scriptfirewallruleout);
        psout.Invoke();
        PowerShell ps3 = PowerShell.Create();
        string starttor = string.Format("tor.exe -f C:\\torrc.txt");
        ps3.AddScript(starttor);
        ps3.Invoke();
        MessageBox.Show("To see tor progress, open the notices.log file. It will be where you set it to be in the torrc configuration above.");



    }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PowerShell ps3 = PowerShell.Create();
        string starttor = string.Format("tor.exe -f C:\\torrc.txt");
        ps3.AddScript(starttor);
        ps3.Invoke();
        MessageBox.Show("To see tor progress, open the notices.log file. It will be where you set it to be in the torrc configuration above.");

       
    }
```

Comment: You nee to break out the task that you run when clicking the button into an async method which the button calls. You may want to consider how to "talk" back to the gui with a progress bar or some other indicator the task is finished. Take a look at this for a good example:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/27c648/making-a-simple-non-freezing-window-forms-application/